# How to block unrecognized hostnames in .htaccess (A Domain Name I Don't Recognize Is Redirecting To My Site)

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ip, .htaccess

I'm using Dedicated IP on a shared linux server... **At first, I saw that an unfamiliar hostname displayed my own website like a mirror.** I scanned the A records of this site to investigate what was going on. And I noticed that my IP address is in the A record of the other domain.

**To resolve this conflict i used the following definition:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.goodsite.\com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://goodsite.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

**This worked. But another problem arose.** **When you click on the website that initially displays my website, it now redirects you to my own domain and website.** In other words, you click on `badsite.com` but you redirect to `goodsite.com`. The two domain names are not related and owned by different entities.

How can I avoid this redirect on my own server?

Comment: This is a really confusing question and you’re not showing A records in your image. You’re showing MX (mail) records. You have no control over someone else’s domain. They can redirect to your site and there is nothing you can do about it. What you can do is configure your sites in Apache so they only respond to your hostname, and show a 404 for any other hostname. I’m not convinced you’re not demonstrating some basic misunderstandings of how all this works.

Comment: I recommend you rewrite the question demonstrating step by step what someone could do to reproduce and see the problem. And if you don’t want to show real domain names (not really any reason not to) then show images or output of your results as you take these steps. It’s not clear what your problem is.

Comment: I made an update, can you check again?

Comment: What do you mean we both have the same ip address and we are both on different server companies? Are you making that statement based on your DNS record lookup? It’s not possible that two different servers from different hosting providers have the same actual IP address. Again, you are showing MX records not A records. The two are for different purposes and MX do not effect the behavior of a web browser or website. Those are for mail flow. All that suggests is that mail for these domains flow to the same mail provider.

Comment: Their site isn't using the same ip address. They've created an A record for their site in their DNS that points to the ip address of your site. You can't do anything about that because you don't have access to their DNS to change the A record. You need to handle this on your site by rejecting connections that originate from their site.

Comment: I was finally able to decipher your question and post an answer and edit your question so it makes more sense.

Comment: "When you click on the website that initially displays my website, it now redirects you to my own domain and website." - Because that is the code you've implemented in `.htaccess` to resolve the initial problem (not because `badsite.com` has adapted their behaviour). If `badsite.com` had implemented the redirect then there would be nothing you could do further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem should be resolved in your virtual host config and not with .htaccess. If you are using a website hosting company and do not have direct access to the Apache virtual host config, then this problem is a direct result of a misconfiguration on the server they manage. Simply put, using a `serverName` directive within a proper virtual host config, your website should only be displayed when someone specifically enters `example1.com` in their browser. You should address this with the provider.

However, similar functionality can be achieved in `.htaccess`.

You can remove the code the provider suggested and instead add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|)example1\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This says for any request that is not [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) or example1.com deny it with an error.

Be careful with your code in .htaccess. You have a typo in your original code and I’m not sure if that is from your provider, from you, or what.

Without seeing your whole .htaccess or knowing how the server is configured, please make sure you can access your site after this change by trying both example1.com and [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) in your browser.

Comment: "using a `serverName` directive within a proper virtual host config, your website should only be displayed when someone specifically enters `example1.com` in their browser" - Unless that virtual host happens to be the first defined `<VirtualHost>`, in which case it becomes the "default" and all requests for non-canonical hostnames will be caught by it.